# how to describe this case with markov-chain

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I want to describe this case in markov chain:

**The case**:
Mr. Meier reads NYTimes everyday and puts the newspaper on news rack. His wife sometimes cleans the house(with prob $1/3$ each day) and throws away all newspapers. If there are 5 or more newspapers on the rack, Mr. Meier throws away them by his own hand. 
Now lets assume, husband and wife are gone to bed. How can i describe the number of newspapers on the news rack with markov chain?

I am kinda stuck, what are the my state spaces here?

Comment: The state space is $[0;5]$ - that is, how many NYT newspapers can be at the rack. In general it shall be $\Bbb N_0$, but you know that $p_{i0} = 1$ for all $i\geq 5$, so you can lump all the states bigger than $4$ in one. I didn't understand, though, what's the order of cleaning/throwing.

Comment: @Ilya, yeaah, you are right, state space are # of newspapers. so it is from 0 to 4, beause if =5 or >5, Mr.Meier throws all away. i will give you a link of what i drawn in a second

Comment: @Ilya, http://imagebin.org/264899, this is what i saw in solution, but i dont understand why $2/3$. can you please take a look?

Comment: @Ilya, i think, now i got it. 2/3 is the prob that wife DOES NOT clean the house, so that #of newspapers can grow. am i right?

Comment: For some reason I thought that wife troughs away only one newspaper (edited).

Comment: @Ilya, oh okay. so this state space is only for one day, right? what does $p_{0,2} = 0$ mean here?

Comment: Ok, $p_{i,i+1} = \frac23$ for $i=0,1,2,3$ (the case when the wife does not clean) and $p_{i,0} = \frac13$ for $i=0,1,2,3$ (the case when the wife does clean). Finally, $p_{4,0} = 1$ thanks to Mr. Meier.

Comment: @Ilya, yeaaah :)) you are right. $p_{0,2} = 0$ means that Mr.Meier doesnot read 2 newspapers at a time?

Comment: At least it seems from the text problem. I don't read NYT, but I guess you get at most one every day.

Comment: @Ilya, you are right, I didnot think about that:). great help! Thank you so much